# Python GUI stays frozen waiting for thread code to finish running

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a python GUI program that needs to do a same task but with several threads. The problem is that I call the threads but they don't execute parallel but sequentially. First one executes, it ends and then second one, etc. I want them to start independently.

The main components are:
 1. Menu (view)
 2. ProcesStarter (controller)
 3. Process (controller)

The **Menu** is where you click on the "Start" button which calls a function at **ProcesStarter**.

The **ProcesStarter** creates objects of **Process** and threads, and starts all threads in a for-loop.

**Menu:**

```
class VotingFrame(BaseFrame):

  def create_widgets(self):
    self.start_process = tk.Button(root, text="Start Process", command=lambda: self.start_process())
    self.start_process.grid(row=3,column=0, sticky=tk.W)

  def start_process(self):
    procesor = XProcesStarter()
    procesor_thread = Thread(target=procesor.start_process())
    procesor_thread.start()
```

**ProcesStarter**:

```
class XProcesStarter:

   def start_process(self):
       print "starting new process..."

       # thread count
       thread_count = self.get_thread_count()

       # initialize Process objects with data, and start threads
       for i in range(thread_count):
          vote_process = XProcess(self.get_proxy_list(), self.get_url())
          t = Thread(target=vote_process.start_process())
          t.start()
```

**Process:**

```
class XProcess():

    def __init__(self, proxy_list, url, browser_show=False):
        # init code

    def start_process(self):
        # code for process
```

When I press the GUI button for "Start Process" the gui is locked until both threads finish execution. 
The idea is that threads should work in the background and work in parallel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to use a class as the `target` of a thread is to use the class as the target, and the arguments to the constructor as `args`.

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
from random import randint

class XProcesStarter:
  def __init__(self, thread_count):
    print ("starting new process...")
    self._i = 0
    for i in range(thread_count):
      t = Thread(
        target=XProcess,
        args=(self.get_proxy_list(), self.get_url())
      )
      t.start()


  def get_proxy_list(self):
    self._i += 1
    return "Proxy list #%s" % self._i

  def get_url(self):
    self._i += 1
    return "URL #%d" % self._i

class XProcess():    
  def __init__(self, proxy_list, url, browser_show=False):
    r = 0.001 * randint( 1, 5000)
    sleep(r)
    print (proxy_list)
    print (url)

def main():
  t = Thread( target=XProcesStarter, args=(4, ) )
  t.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

This code runs in python2 and python3.

The reason is that the target of a Thread object must be a callable (search for "callable" and "__call__" in python documentation for a complete explanation).

**Edit** The other way has been explained in other people's answers (see Tadhg McDonald-Jensen).

Comment: not completely accurate, `Thread(target=None).start()` is completely valid, not to mention that a method on an object is callable so there is nothing wrong with initializing it first then running the method in a thread.

Comment: Thanks!  I learned something today!  (I will also edit my answer)

Comment: and I like it better structured this way 

Answer (score 3):

you call `procesor.start_process()` immediately when specifying it as the target of the Thread:

```
#use this
procesor_thread = Thread(target=procesor.start_process)

#not this
procesor_thread = Thread(target=procesor.start_process())
                          # this is called right away ^
```

If you call it right away it returns None which is a valid target for Thread (it just does nothing) which is why it happens sequentially, the threads are not doing anything.

Comment: This would have actually worked as well, quicker edit than @Sci Prog's answer. But I understand now why :)

Answer (score 2):

I think your issue is that in both places you're starting threads, you're actually calling the method you want to pass as the `target` to the thread. That runs its code in the main thread (and tries to start the new thread on the return value, if any, once its done).

Try:

```
procesor_thread = Thread(target=procesor.start_process) # no () after start_process
```

And:

```
t = Thread(target=vote_process.start_process) # no () here either
```

Comment: Thanks, get it now. Was asking myself why it was being called straight by just saying `target=procesor.start_process()`